# Error Interceptor for ngrx 4 effects

Tags: angular, ngrx, sentry, ngrx-effects

I want to send errors to a service like Sentry, but ngrx 4 doesn't use Angular's ErrorHandler.
How can I create a global error interceptor for ngrx 4 effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/635 allows to use Angular's ErrorHandler or a custom one by adding `{ provide: ErrorReporter, useClass: CustomErrorHandler },`
to your providers.

The error message will only contain `Error: Effect "EffectsClass.EffectName$" threw an error`.
The real error will be available in `error.Notification.error`.

This is not yet released, and only available in the nightly builds (ngrx/entity-builds). In ngrx 5, providing a custom ErrorHandler will be enough to catch effects errors.